# Why is inclusion of Kafka breaking my Spring controller's unit test?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am creating a Spring Boot web application that will utilise Kafka.  I have created a trivial controller that will return a string.

```
// src/main/groovy/RootController.groovy

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody


/**
 * Controller to serve the index page
 */
@Controller
class RootController {

    /**
     * Serves the index page
     *
     * @return A string to appear on the index page
     */

    @GetMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String loadPage() {
        return "root/index"
    }

}
```

I have a unit test for this that uses Spock.

```
// src/test/groovy/RootControllerTest.groovy

import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders
import spock.lang.Specification

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

@WebAppConfiguration
class RootControllerTest extends Specification {

    MockMvc mockMvc

    // Setup for tests happens here˚
    void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new RootController()).build()
    }

    // Cleanup for tests happens here
    void cleanup() {}

    def "LoadPage should return the string root/index"() {
        when: 'the loadPage endpoint is hit'
        def response = mockMvc.perform(get("/"))

        then: 'the method loadPage returns the string root/index'
        response.andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string("root/index"))

    }

}
```

When run, this test passes.  I have the following `build.gradle` file that will build and run the tests.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.1.RELEASE'   // Spring Boot
}

group 'dummy'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = '3.1'
  distributionUrl = "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-$gradleVersion-all.zip"
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
def kafkaVersion = '0.10.0.0'

repositories {
    maven {
        name "confluent"
        url "http://packages.confluent.io/maven/"
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4"                      // Groovy version
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"    // For thymeleaf


    //compile "org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.11:${kafkaVersion}-cp1"         // Kafka, as produced by confluent, hence -cp1 suffix


    // Testing dependencies go here
    testCompile "org.springframework:spring-test:4.3.6.RELEASE"
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4"          // Spock (Mandatory)
}
```

However, when I uncomment the Kafka dependency, the build fails like this:

```
$ gradle clean test
:clean
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestGroovy
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test

RootControllerTest > LoadPage should return the string root/index FAILED
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at RootControllerTest.groovy:21
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at RootControllerTest.groovy:21

1 test completed, 1 failed
:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

What is it that is causing the failure please?

Comment: Have you tried running your `gradle` job as verbose to check for any buried exceptions?

Comment: Well probably because you are using Spring Boot, which will try to auto configure Kafka when that is detected on your class path. But it cannot auto configure it because there is no Kafka instance running, hence your test fails to even start. (Which is why you get an `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`.

Comment: @timothyclifford Thanks, that highlighted that `Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND bound slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path` was the issue.  After following the code here I fixed the issue (http://buransky.com/programming/exclude-log4j-to-use-slf4j-with-logback-in-a-gradle-project/)

Comment: Good to hear @John! Feel free to give my comment a tick ;)